# Multiple checkboxes, if correct change background image (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, image, checkbox, background

Theres a form with 4 answers. 2 of them are correct. If both answered are checked, there should appear some button to check if the correct ones are selected. If that is the case, the background image is supposed to change.

Comment: Post here what you have tried.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> 
var checkflag = "false";

function check(field) {
    if (checkflag == "false") {

        for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            field[i].checked = true;
        }
        checkflag = "true";
        return " keine ";
    } else {


        for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            field[i].checked = false;
        }
        checkflag = "false";
        return " alle ";
    }
}
  </script>

Comment: <form name="myform" action="" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="2">
   <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="3">
   <input type="checkbox" onchange="submit();" name="list" value="4">
   <input type="submit" value=" Überprüfen " 
   onClick="this.value=check(this.form.list)">   i didnt do much yet, im new to javascript, i dont know how to format this here :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".checkBoxClass").click(function(){
    if($(".chckBoxClass:checked").length >= 2){
        $("#buttonID").show();
    }else{
        $("#buttonID").hide();
    }
});

$("#buttonID").click(function(){
    //code to check answer.
    if(answerFlag == true){
        $(".divBackground").css("background-color", "colour");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, ive tried, but it doesnt generate a button when 2 answers are  checked

Comment: It will not generate a button. You have to create a button, which is hidden by default. (Eg. <input type="submit" id="buttonID" style="display:none;" />)